# A combinatorial number theory question (pigeonhole principle)

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer such that $n$ and $10$ are coprime. Prove that $n|11\cdots11$ for some $11\cdots11$ in base 10 representation.

This problem is about pigeonhole principle, I have a great difficulty in setting up the pigeonhole. Is there any general rule of thumbs in setting up them? thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you see such questions, try to find the pigeons first!

*Hint*: Consider the sequence $1,11,111,1111,...,\overbrace{11\cdots 11}^{n+1 \;\text{times}}$ as pigeons.

Can you conclude from here?

**Remark**: Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Given $n+1$ integers $a_1,\cdots,a_{n+1}$ there exist $i\neq j,$ s.t. $a_i \equiv a_j \;(\text{mod}\; n).$

The key is to write each number $a_k=nq_k+r_k$ where $0\leq r_k \leq n-1$ and observe that since each $r_k$ varies from $0$ to $n-1$ and there are $n$ possibilities, by taking $0,1,\cdots,n-1$ as pigeonholes and $r_k$s as pigeons, one would conclude that at least two pigeons (*i.e.* at least two $a_k$s) share the same pigeonholes (*i.e.* have the same remainder).

**Possible next exercise**:

> Show that there is a power of $n$ which terminates in $0001$ in base $10.$

Comment: I have trouble understanding your hint. How does it conclude every $n$ co prime to $10$ divides $111\dots 11$?

Comment: @Inceptio A further hint would be to look at the residues modulo $n$. What happens if two of the numbers are congruent?

Comment: I think those are rather the pigeons (unless you are using a version of the pigeonhole principle where one is putting $n+1$ holes into $n$ pigeons;-). The holes are the classes modulo$~n$.

Comment: @Inceptio: Can you show that given $n+1$ integers there exist at least two of them with the same remainder modulo $n$ ( when dividing by $n$)?

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani I would definite edit the answer to address Marc's comment. The answer as it stands is probably a bit confusing unless you already know the solution beforehand.

Comment: @EuYu: I was rather confused by $n+1$ pigeonholes. The same presence of same remainders is staring at me.

Comment: @Inceptio I'm not too sure what you're asking here.

Comment: @EuYu: How would you react if it was something like 'If $n$ is such a number that it divides $11…11$, prove that all $n$  are co-prime to $10$ and the hint of PigeonHole principle isn't given to you'.

Comment: @Inceptio: I have added more explanations as EuYu suggested.

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani: Seems pretty fine. Actually, I'm not the OP, just a keen learner.:)

Comment: Nice solution! Just substract two numbers which are on the same "pigeonhole" and use that $n$ and $10$ are coprime.